# I find correct limit of the sin cos function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

This is no homeworks I only do for learn.

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{1+\cos x}$$

I use l'Hôpital rule because no idea where limit go for both.

Top is called $g(x)$ and bottom is $h(x)$

$g'(x) = 2\sin x\cos x$

$h'(x) = -\sin x$

$\Rightarrow $

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi}\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{-\sin x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \pi}-2\cos x = 2$

So my limit is $2$.

Is that correct or do I do some maths mistake? Please tell me all mistakes I make and be very strict. Because in exam is very strict.

Comment: This looks very well done !

Comment: You wrote that you have no idea where the limit goes for both, but $\lim_{x \to \pi} \cos(x) = -1$ so the denominator goes to $0$ and the numerator goes to $0$ as well, since $\sin(\pi) = 0$.

Comment: Just as Newb commented, what you missed is to check that you face a $\frac00$ or $\frac \infty\infty$ problem. Otherwise, no LH rule.

Comment: You might compare doing the limit without l'Hopital, by multiplying numerator and denominator by $1-\cos x$.

Comment: How can I make check? Please tell me :)
I maybe know but not know in good formal maths.
And I always need check before use Hopital yes?

So I show that top go to zero as example and under also and because 0/0 is Hopital i use it right?

Comment: $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)=\bigl(1-\cos(x)\bigr)\bigl(1+\cos(x)\bigr)$.  Now cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do no mistake; remember to check that
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi}g(x)=0
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\pi}h(x)=0
$$
(or both $\infty$) and that the derivative of $h$ is not zero in some neighborhood of $\pi$, so l'Hôpital can be applied.

However, there's an easier way:
$$
\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)
$$

Comment: egreg how you make my function bigger?

Comment: @cnmesr Click on the “edit” button and you'll see; I've been using TeX for a “few” years, so I know quite a lot of tricks

Answer (score 3):

What about
$$ \lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{1+\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \pi}(1-\cos x) = 1-\cos\pi = \color{red}{2} $$
?